# Difficult Slow speed splitter file txt?

Tags: c#, file, split

I wrote a program that split txt files into smaller pieces
But my problem is that my method is slow
Because this file size is 1gb and I use a variable named "pagesize"  which  base on that amount of lines in splitted files will be calculated

**The problem is that the foreach is slow?**

**Is there a better way?**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string inputFile = @"G:\Programming\C#\c# tamrin reza\large-Orders.txt";

        int seed = 1000;
        const int pageSize = 5000;
        int count = 1;
        const string destinationFileName = @"F:\Output\";
        string outputFile;
        string baseName = "-CustomerApp";
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(inputFile);
        var lst = new List<string>();
        //FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(inputFile);
        //long fileSize = fileInfo.Length / pageSize;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= pageSize; j++)
            {
                var line = sr.ReadLine();
                lst.Add(line);
            }
            outputFile = destinationFileName + count + baseName + extension;
            CopyLines(lst, outputFile);
            lst.Clear();
            count++;
        }
    }

    private void CopyLines(List<string> line, string outputFile)
    {
        FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        //StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFile);
        //for (int i = 1; i < line.Count; i++)
        //{
        //}
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFileStream))
        {
            foreach (var li in line)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(li);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you identified what part of the loop is the issue? I suspect it's streaming out the lines to another file via `CopyLines`. Can you verify that?

Comment: It is slow because you doing this on a jiggabyte file.  It will never be faster than 20 seconds.  And can be a *lot* slower than that if the disk is fragmented, write a directory with umpteen files or you don't have enough RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the entire collection twice.  If you write to the output file while you are reading, that will save one iteration over the entire collection.

```
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        outputFile = destinationFileName + count + baseName + extension;
        FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outputFileStream))
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= pageSize; j++)
            {
                var line = sr.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(li);
            }
        }
        lst.Clear();
        count++;
    }
```